# Create a new javascript object with only selected attributes from another existing object

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-objects

I have a `javascript object` and I want to create a new one with only some of its attributes.

How can I create a new object with only attributes `a` and `c` from the below object ?

```
json = {
  "test": [
        {
            "a": "val_a1",
            "b": "val_b1",
            "c": "val_c1",
            "d": "val_d1"
        },
        {
            "a": "val_a2",
            "b": "val_b2",
            "c": "val_c2",
            "d": "val_d2"
        },
        {
            "a": "val_a3",
            "b": "val_b3",
            "c": "val_c3",
            "d": "val_d3"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want a new object with data like:

```
smaller_json = {
    "test": [
        {
            "c": "val_a1",
            "a": "val_c1"
        },
        {
            "c": "val_a2",
            "a": "val_c2"
        },
        {
            "c": "val_a3",
            "a": "val_c3"
        }
    ]
};
```

Comment: Decode, remove, encode again. Doing string manipulation on JSON does not look sensible.

Comment: Whenever you have large amount of JavaScript code, and you want to test if you have correct syntax...JSON format you can use www.jsonlint.com. its a nice tool...check it out if you have not seen it before....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/X5L8w/)**

code:

```
var json = {
  "test": [
        {
            "a": "val_a1",
            "b": "val_b1",
            "c": "val_c1",
            "d": "val_d1"
        },
        {
            "a": "val_a2",
            "b": "val_b2",
            "c": "val_c2",
            "d": "val_d2"
        },
        {
            "a": "val_a3",
            "b": "val_b3",
            "c": "val_c3",
            "d": "val_d3"
        }
    ]
};

var new_json = {test:{}};
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.each(json.test, function(key, value){
        //console.log("key = "+key);
        //console.log("value = ");
        //console.log(value);
        var new_obj = {};
        new_obj.a = value.a;
        new_obj.c = value.c;
        new_json.test[key] = new_obj;
    });

    console.log("new_json = ");
    console.log(new_json);//here new_json will only contain attributes "a" and "c" only
});
```